# What is the problem with linking to the equation in MathJax tutorial?

Tags: support, mathjax

When I try out the following: `$$x^3+y^3=z^3 \tag{*} \label{*}$$`
$$x^3+y^3=z^3 \tag{*} \label{*}$$
then \eqref{*} shows as it should.

And if I enter the url obtained from there: `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17193/what-characters-is-allowed-to-be-used-in-tag-label-of-an-equation#mjx-eqn-*` it [links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17193/what-characters-is-allowed-to-be-used-in-tag-label-of-an-equation#mjx-eqn-*) to this equation. (For example, if I enter it into a new browser window, this post is displayed and browser shows the part containing the equation.

When I try to copy the link in the same way from the post [explaining how to use labels and tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/11491#11491) in our MathJax tutorial I get [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/11491#mjx-eqn-*) which does not behave as expected. (If you click on the link or enter it in a new browser window, you will be shown the beginning of the question.) Why does it behave differently on that particular post?

Comment: I was tempted to tag this as ([meta-tag:bug]). Bus since I am not sure whether it is indeed a bug, I have chosen (support) instead.

Comment: Browser/OS? Asking because it works fine for me... provided I wait 10 seconds or so for the MathJax processing to continue to the point where that equation appears.

Comment: Incidentally, this probably means that that page has too much MathJax on it, with my quad core Xeon taking non-trivial time to process it.

Comment: @WillieWong That's it. I simply did not wait long enough. (I saw that the top of the page was rendered, so it did not occur to me to wait any longer.) If you post this explanation as an answer, I will accept it. (I do not know to which extent it is probable that someone might face the same problem. Not very probable, but the post will probably not do much harm staying here, either.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you just need to wait long enough.

MathJax can take some time to process and the links to the tagged equations are not generated until MathJax has processed the relevant equations. In this post since MathJax is not heavily used the processing is almost instantaneous. On the linked page where the "problem" was observed, there were so many MathJax expressions that it took about 10 second for my quad core Xeon to process enough equations that the link is generated.